# Recursive realloc() throw "invalid next size" after the 7th cicle

Tags: c, pointers, int, malloc, realloc

So, I have a pointer which need to increase it's "length" until the user insert a negative number or "e". It starts with the length of "1", via a `malloc()` then I use into a `do{...} while(...)` loop the `realloc()` function to increase its lenght. Here's the code:

```
int *array = malloc (sizeof(int) * 1);
bool exit = false;
int lastIndex = 0, value;

do {
    printf ("Insert a positive number. Insert a negative number or \"e\" to exit:  ");

    int scanf_result = scanf("%i", &value);
    if (scanf_result) {
      if (value >= 0) {
        array[lastIndex] = value;
        lastIndex++;
        array = (int*) realloc (array, lastIndex * sizeof(int));
      } else {
        exit = true;
      }
    } else {
      exit = true;
    }
} while (!exit);
```

I can't figure out why after the 7th cicle it exit with the error `realloc(): invalid next size`.

Any idea? Thanks in advice for help.

Comment: regarding: `int scanf_result = scanf("%i", &value);
    if (scanf_result)`  the returned value from 'this' call to `scanf()`  can return 0, 1, or EOF.  So the `if()` statement is not valid.  It should be: `if( scanf_result == 1 )`  Any other returned value indicates an error occurred.

Comment: regarding: `array = (int*) realloc (array, lastIndex * sizeof(int));`  1) in C, the returned value from `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc`  has type `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer,   Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) When calling `realloc()`, never assign the returned value directly to the target pointer.  Rather assign to a 'temp' variable, then check (!=NULL) and if successful, then assign the target pointer from the temp pointer.  Otherwise when `realloc()` fails the original pointer is lost, resulting in a memory leak

Comment: regarding: `printf ("Insert a positive number. Insert a negative number or \"e\" to exit:  ");`  which suggests to enter 'e'.  That 'e' will never by input by the statement: `if (scanf_result) {` due to the format string: "%i".  However, that may be handled correctly by the program.  However, if the user enters <ctrl-d> (or <ctrl-z>) depending on the OS, that will be seen as a valid input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not reallocating enough memory:

```
array = (int*) realloc (array, lastIndex * sizeof(int));
```

On the first iteration of the loop, `lastIndex` is incremented from 0 to 1, then you run the above `realloc` call.  Since `lastIndex` is 1, you still only have enough space for 1 element.  As a result, you write past the end of allocated memory on the next iteration.

This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in your case manifests as appearing to work properly for the first 6 iterations and failing on the 7th.  It could have just as easily crashed on the first or second iteration.

Add one to the size you're allocating:

```
array = realloc(array, (lastIndex + 1) * sizeof(int));
```

Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc`/`realloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 0):

Fix your `realloc`:

```
array = (int*) realloc (array, (lastIndex + 1) * sizeof(int))
```

You are allocating one item less than you need to.